# Border to triangle disappears when zooming out and collapse when zooming in

Tags: html, css

So I have to do tabs and I done them by creating triangles with pseudo-elements that were made with the help of borders and applied a filter: drop-shadow to them to show borders to border. In 100% zoom, everything is fine, but if you zooming out it, the borders with pseudo-elements disappers, and if you zooming in it, they collapse. What can you advise to solve this problem?

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
 font-size: 14px;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 40px;
 height: 34px;
 bottom: -6px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000; 
}
.tab:before {
  content: '';
 left: -14px;
 position: absolute;
 border: 31px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
 border-right: 0px solid transparent;
 border-left: 14px solid #f0f0f0;
 bottom: 0;
 filter: drop-shadow(1px 0px 0px black);
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transform-origin: bottom;
}
.tab:after {
  content: '';
 right: -14px;
 position: absolute;
 border: 31px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
 border-right: 0px solid transparent;
 border-left: 14px solid #f0f0f0;
 bottom: 0;
 filter: drop-shadow(1px 0px 0px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab"><a>tab1</a></div>
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkehqg0j/12

Comment: try position in `%` not `px` like: `right:3%`

Comment: collapsed in this way